# Choosing GDM login window theme via GUI without Ubuntu Tweak

Tags: 10.04, themes, gdm

Is there any way to (via the GUI) modify the theme that is used for the GDM login system?  I ask because when I installed `xubuntu-desktop` alongside `gnome-desktop` the `xubuntu-gdm-theme` package took over the login window theme.  Is there any easy method to have multiple GDM themes installed at once, but be able to choose which theme takes dominance in the login manager without removing all other theme packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach**

If you don't like Ubuntu Tweak, may be you like the GDM2 Setup tool:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gdm2setup/gdm2setup
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-gdm2setup
```

---

**Second approach**

[TheeMahn](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=2&sid=20e44b5a1e7a9f384d7a74e852ada7b4) has made a Nautilus script that help you to easily make your GDM theme:

```
cd ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/
wget http://ubuntusoftware.info/scripts/MakeGDM
sudo chmod +x MakeGDM
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this allow me to modify only the login theme without modifying the other theme(s)?

Comment: Was getting a lot of python errors in a test installation, i think i'll hold out until its got something >= 1.0.0.  Any other suggestions are accepted :)

Comment: Added a second approach =-)

Comment: @desgua, you wouldn't happen to be using Kubuntu would ya?

Comment: @EvilPhoenix, no I'm not, are you?

Comment: No, but that screenshot made me think Kubuntu for a minute :/

Comment: The screenshot is from the author of the script ;-)

Comment: MY EYES. THEY BLEED. Ugly theme in screenshots :/

Answer (score 1):

Since the time of this thread being posted, I have switched to using KDE as my primary environment, and have been able to successfully theme the KDM login window.

I will mark @desgua's answer as the accepted answer, but I wanted to make a note that I switched.

Comment: I'm thinking in switching too but I'm afraid to miss Compiz...